# how to declare c# dll functions dynamically in c++ builder

Tags: c++

i tried the code shown below  to call a c# dll function (COM) but when i do that i get the errors below "Invalid use of namespace 'MaxElementFn'"

My guess is that maybe i am calling the c# dll function incorrectly in c++ builder. any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. thank  you in advance.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

using MaxElementFn = int(__stdcall *) (int a, int b);

int main()

{

  HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("ExportedCodeSolution.dll");


  MaxElementFn maxElement = reinterpret_cast<MaxElementFn>(GetProcAddress(mod, "maxElement"));


  std::printf("max: %d\n", maxElement(1, 2));


}

[BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(145): E2070 Invalid use of namespace 'MaxElementFn'
[BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(151): E2451 Undefined symbol 'MaxElementFn'
```

these are the errors i am getting

Answer (score 0):

```
// helper template
template<typename T> 
bool GetFuncPointer(HMODULE module, const char* name, T& ptr)
{
  ptr = (T)GetProcAddress(module, name);
  if(!ptr) std::printf("function not found in dll: %s\n", name);
  return ptr != nullptr;
}

// declare func pointer
int (__stdcall * maxElement) (int, int) = nullptr;

int main()
{
    HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("ExportedCodeSolution.dll");

    // make sure we actually have the function before calling
    if(GetFuncPointer(mod, "maxElement", maxElement))
    {
      std::printf("max: %d\n", maxElement(1, 2));
    }

    return 0;
}
```